# How to group letters in OpenCV knowing their RotatedRects?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, image-rotation

I have an image with letters, for example like this:
[image: ala]

It's a binary image obtained from previous image processing stages and I know [boundingRect](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gacb413ddce8e48ff3ca61ed7cf626a366) and [RotatedRect](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/db/dd6/classcv_1_1RotatedRect.html) of every letter, but these letters are not grouped in words yet. It is worth mentioning, that RotatedRect can be returned from minAreaRect() or fitEllipse(), what is shown [here](https://namkeenman.wordpress.com/tag/rotatedrect/) and [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-rc1/de/d62/tutorial_bounding_rotated_ellipses.html). In my case RotatedRects look like this:

[image]

Blue rectangles are obtained from minAreaRect and red are obtained from fitEllipse. They give a little different boxes (center, width, height, angle), but the biggest difference is in values of angle. In first option angle changes from -90 to 0 degrees , in second case angle changes from 0 to 180 degrees. My problem is: how to group these letters in words, basing on parameters of RotatedRects? I can check angle of every RotatedRect and also measure distance between centers of every two RotatedRects. With simple assumptions on direction of text and distance between letters my algorithm of grouping works. But in more complicated case I encounter a problem. For example, in the image below there are few groups of text, with different directions, different angles and distances between letters. 
[image]
Problems are when letter from one word is close to letter from other word and when angle of RotatedRect inside given word is more different than the angles of its neighbours. What could be the best way to connect letters in right words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to define metric. It may be Euclidian 3D distance for example, defined as ||delta_X,delta_y,Delta_angle|| , where delta_X and delta_Y are distances beetween rectangle centers along x and y coordinate, and Delta_angle as a distance between angular orientation. 
In short, your rectangles transforms to 3D data points, with coordinates (x,y,angle).

After you define this. You can use clusetering algorithm on your data. Seems DBSCAN should work good here. Check this article for example: [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/the-5-clustering-algorithms-data-scientists-need-to-know-a36d136ef68)  it may help to choose clustering  algorithm.

Comment: I extended the aforementioned metric by a few other elements related to geometric properties of letters and words (distances, angles, areas, a ratio of neighbouring letters areas etc.) and now it works fine. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I extended the aforementioned metric by a few other elements related to geometric properties of letters and words (distances, angles, areas, a ratio of neighboring letters areas, etc.) and now it works fine. Thanks for the suggestion.